# Get video source from youtube video

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-data-api

I need a video `src` from youtube video.
I tried to read the file using `php` but in youtube's view source there is no `video` tag, So this method is not usefull.
Is there any other way to get the video src?
Can I get it using `youtube api v3`?
 [playit.pk](http://playit.pk) run all youtube videos that's mean there is way to get src.
Please help me about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't download youtube videos using the YouTube API, however, there's 2 ways to download YouTube videos using PHP:

1. Using [get_video_info](https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=VIDEO_ID). This url contains all the information of the video you want, but you can only download public videos.
2. [Youtube-Downloader](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader/) method. Everything is in the README.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can't use YouTube Api for getting video source. You can get source of public video easily by using this simple script in different formats. https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader It can't get source of copyright videos which needs cipher signature decoding method which is hard to code because YouTube change its method frequently.

Answer (score 0):

```
//http://vamos.pk/watch.php?v=HCO7BWbKipU http://vamos.pk/watch.php?v=UddlsDsoIWs
$url = "https://baixaryoutube.net/en/@api/json/videos/".$get_v_id;

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$jsonurl = json_decode($json);

$vidInfo[] = array();


foreach ($jsonurl as $key => $value) {

     if ($key == "vidInfo") 
     {
       $vidInfo[] = $value;
     }
}
//var_dump($jsonurl);
//var_dump($vidInfo);
```